How to use MinGW's gcc compiler when installing Python package using Pip for python 3.12 and higher?
I configured MinGW and distutils so now I can compile extensions using Cython, and it works fine instead of giving error. But the same error shows up when I want to install pip package which does not have a wheel.
I know there is similar question:here but this solution is not valid for python versions higher than 3.12 because of this and there is no \Lib\distutils catalog.
Error I'm getting:
  exit code: 1
  
  [5 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'PyQt6.sip' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyQt6-sip
Failed to build PyQt6-sip
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (PyQt6-sip)

Same error for setuptools cython was solved by passing --compiler=mingw32 and installing compiler

I'm a bit puzzled by the Cython tag - PyQt6 definitely doesn't use Cython.

Oh i add this since I have it there and it works while compiling do you suggest removing?

Yes I think so. I understand why you added it now after your comment, but the relation seems fairly vague
